# I got different result in ESQL vs EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

There is a table with next structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Replp2pPhone](
 [Phone] [bigint] NULL,
 [SubNetId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [DateFrom] [date] NOT NULL,
 [DateTo] [date] NOT NULL,
 [InTransactions] [int] NULL,
 [OutTransactions] [int] NULL,
 [InUniquePhones] [int] NULL,
 [OutUniquePhones] [int] NULL,
 [MoneyIn] [money] NULL,
 [MoneyOut] [money] NULL,
 [MoneyFill] [money] NULL,
 [MoneyPays] [money] NULL,
 [PaymentsCount] [int] NULL,
 [Geo] [varchar](1024) NULL
)
```

I realize paging with the next code through entity framework:

```
 int pageNumber = 0;
            int pageSize = 250000;
            Replp2pPhone[] phones;

                do
                {

                    var context = new GraphTestEntities();
                    context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

                    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    // here isn't correct result.
                    phones = context.Replp2pPhone
                        .OrderBy(p=>p.SubNetId)
                        .ThenBy(p=>p.Phone)
                        .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize).ToArray();

                    context.Dispose();
                //    Insert(phones);
                    pageNumber++;
                } while (phones.Length == pageSize);

                    var phone = phones.Where(p => p.Phone == 00000000);
```

Entity Framework generate next ESQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Extent1].[SubNetId] AS [SubNetId], 
    [Extent1].[DateFrom] AS [DateFrom], 
    [Extent1].[DateTo] AS [DateTo], 
    [Extent1].[InTransactions] AS [InTransactions], 
    [Extent1].[OutTransactions] AS [OutTransactions], 
    [Extent1].[InUniquePhones] AS [InUniquePhones], 
    [Extent1].[OutUniquePhones] AS [OutUniquePhones], 
    [Extent1].[MoneyIn] AS [MoneyIn], 
    [Extent1].[MoneyOut] AS [MoneyOut], 
    [Extent1].[MoneyFill] AS [MoneyFill], 
    [Extent1].[MoneyPays] AS [MoneyPays], 
    [Extent1].[PaymentsCount] AS [PaymentsCount], 
    [Extent1].[Geo] AS [Geo]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [Replp2pPhone].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[SubNetId] AS [SubNetId], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[DateFrom] AS [DateFrom], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[DateTo] AS [DateTo], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[InTransactions] AS [InTransactions], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[OutTransactions] AS [OutTransactions], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[InUniquePhones] AS [InUniquePhones], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[OutUniquePhones] AS [OutUniquePhones], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[MoneyIn] AS [MoneyIn], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[MoneyOut] AS [MoneyOut], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[MoneyFill] AS [MoneyFill], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[MoneyPays] AS [MoneyPays], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[PaymentsCount] AS [PaymentsCount], 
    [Replp2pPhone].[Geo] AS [Geo]
    FROM [dbo].[Replp2pPhone] AS [Replp2pPhone]) AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[SubNetId] ASC, [Extent1].[Phone] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 250000 ROWS ONLY
```

The issue: Result ESQL is correct, but result in array phones isn't correct and different from ESQL's result and has dublicate rows and some rows is missing.

Comment: Have you defined a PK for your entity (table)? If not, it's time to do it.

Comment: It doesn't look like he has a key defined.

Comment: I don't understand why without PK I have got incorrect result?